# Moving multiple classes to another package and reconfiguring the package in each file

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, package, file-moving

I have a lot of classes within a package and I have to move them to another package. I'm using Eclipse IDE and after moving them, I have this problem of editing each class file's first line (the "package" line)

For example, I have to change the line:

```
package abc.def.xyz;
```

to

```
package abc.def.hij.xyz;
```

is there a better way than to open each file and manually do it? I'm not a familiar with the IDE and I've looked around for a better way in Google but no solution yet. I have a lot fo things to move.

Comment: How did you move them? The **Refactor** menu is supposed to handle this for you.

Answer (score 7):

The error will come in case where you are manually moving classes directly to another package in your workspace.
Instead of doing this go to **package explorer** of your Eclipse IDE, I guess there will be multiple packages in your *projectname->src* folder(If it is simple java project type).
Now just select the java files from one package in your *package explorer* and drag them to target package.
Doing this will show a "*Move*" popup with auto selected checkbox "*update references to classname.java*", just press Ok.
This will just change the reference of your classes and you do not have to change the package name manually to all of your classes.

I hope this helped.:)